# Categorizing values and grouping by year?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with numbers (between 10 and 30) each day for 5 years. I want to know how many days per year are between 24 and 26, 26 and 28, and 28 and 30.

I think I should categorise the data (so any values between 10 and 24 become 0, 24 and 26 become 1, 26 and 28 become 2, 28 and 30 become 3) and then group by year?

Data:

```
set.seed(22)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2000/01/01"), by = "day", length.out = 1825)
numbers <- sample(10:30, 1825, replace=TRUE)
df1 <- data.frame(dates, numbers)
```

I tried this to categorise the data:

```
Test <- cut(df1$numbers, 
        breaks = c(10, 24, 26, 28, 30), 
        labels = c("0", "1", "2", "3"))
```

It seems to work, I get NAs so I presume I need to work on the values for cut. Then how would I count occurrences per year?

So I would know in 2000 there are x days when between 24 and 26 and so on....

Comment: For the NAs issue, you probably want `include.lowest = TRUE` in `cut()`.

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you!